# Global name 'display' is not defined during "exec()"

Tags: python, networking

I tried executing a simple line drawing program using exec().
It worked fine. But when I tried to execute the same program by sending it through a tcp/ip network(the server reads the program and sends it to the client which receives it to a variable(b) of string type) and then i use exec(b) in the client to execute it but it says:
NameError: global name 'display' is not defined

The line drawing code is:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
import sys

name = 'line'

def display():
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
 glPushMatrix()
 glTranslatef(-1,-1,0)
 gluLookAt(
  0.1, 0.1, 0.3,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

 glLineWidth(3.0)
 color = [1.,1.,1.,1.]
 glBegin(GL_LINES)
 glVertex3f(0,0,0) # origin of the line
 glVertex3f(.5,1.0,.9) # ending point of the line
 glEnd()
 glPopMatrix()
 glutSwapBuffers()
 return
def main():
 glutInit(sys.argv)
 print 'hello'
 glutCreateWindow(name)
 glClearColor(0.4,0.5,0.3,1.0)
 glutDisplayFunc(display)
 glutMainLoop()
 return
main()
```

This part of the client code receives the program and stores it into the variable and then we use exec():

```
while f: 
   a = client.recv(1024)
   if a=="#p":
    f=0
    break
   b+=a

  print b

  exec(b)
```

The code executes upto the part where print hello is given and then stops.

The error message:

```
hello
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "r13client.py", line 31, in run
    exec(b)
  File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 31, in main
NameError: global name 'display' is not defined
```

I am unable to understand what is going wrong here. If anyone could help I'd be grateful.

Comment: Wait, what? Do you send that whole code over the network and then exec() it on the client!? That is probably *not* the right way to implement whatever you are trying to implement. :)

Comment: You have asked three questions. You all use the same title "Network programming in Python", even though your examples contain no network programming. Also, you *never* answer the questions people ask you. This is not the correct way to get help on Stackoverflow.

Comment: yes i do send the whole code. my friends and I are trying to create a network rendering engine in OpenGl. We've just started with it and are trying to send code and get it executed. These are just the starting steps. We have no prior knowledge in python or Opengl(we're learning as we do the project), and not much experience in network programming either so if someone could help us we'd be grateful.

Comment: hello TryPyPy...
print b prints the received program. we did that to check if the whole progrm is being received.

Comment: Sending the code over the network is the wrong solution. Don't do that. Define up the rendering functions in the rendering machine, and send only data. ie, send "drawLine 0 0 45 67" to draw a line from 0,0 to 45,67. Don't send a function that draws a line. Thats crazy...  In short: **Don't use `exec()`**

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the string you send and then exec?

Your error sounds like you only send the main() function, which won't work.

Comment: The whole program 'to draw the line'(that i've posted above) is sent through the network to the client and stored in the variable 'b'. I gave a print statement in the client side i.e. to print b. the whole prgram gets printed, so the whole program is being sent and stored in the variable. I tried sending a simple program print 'hello world' with a function and it shows the same error. There is some problem when i use functions. How can I make it work?

Comment: the simple program i tried:
def hel():
 print 'hello world'
 return
def main():
 hel()
main()

error:
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "r13client.py", line 31, in run
    exec(b)
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in main
NameError: global name 'hel' is not defined

Comment: @Ani Sunny: Well, that's an interesting error you have there. I can't imagine why. But your solution are without a doubt wrong. Don't send a whole program back and forth like this there is no reason for you to do it. Instead, define display() and main() on the server, and send only the parameters over the net. Problem solved.

Comment: hello.. I found a way to remove the error and get the program running. I declared the display function inside a class and stored the class in a global variable. Then while calling the function, the variable acts as an object of the class (variable.function_name). I got this idea from the net itself. This was just to see if i can send code from a system to another and get it executed there on the other system. To create a network rendering engine parts of the whole rendering program will be divided among the different computers in the network right? That's why i tried this.

Comment: I am working on a way to draw a single line by diving the task among two different systems. Half the line by one system and half by the other. I'm trying to find a way to do that.

Comment: @Ani Sunny: That's a cool project. But *please* stop sending code between two different systems. Send data instead.

Comment: but how will that work? the program is in the server and i want to make use of the client system by executing the code there. How will I do that without sending the code there?

Comment: @Ari Sunny: You have the code there from the start, and you just send data of WHAT to render. The client system should contain all the functions you want to execute from the start, and you only send the *parameters*. You know functions can take arguments, right?

Comment: :) sure I do.I have a doubt(sorry if its stupid),I dont really have an exact idea of how this rendering engine will work, I've just started with it, see if I dont send the code,and if the functions that a program uses is specific to that program, that would mean having a copy of the program I need to execute in all the systems in the network, right?

Comment: @Ani Sunny: Yes, of course. But you need a copy of *a* program on all systems anyway. You just include the functions you need to call in the client code.

Comment: I don't know how I'm going to split my rendering program among the systems in the network yet. Maybe once I find that out I'll be able to figure out how the data needs to be transfered as you are saying. Im really grateful that you're taking interest in helping me.

Comment: @Ani Sunny: How you are going to split it makes no difference. Do *not* send code. Install the code on each machine. Then send commands and arguments to the machines, and send back the result of the rendering. The end.

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Ani Sunny: Do what? You already have figured out all of the above, except that instead of data you send code. send data instead. Done. It's that easy. If you still don't understand, post a new question where you explain what you want to do, what you have tried and how that doesn't work.

Comment: I meant,split the rendering job and then transfer data to get it done by different systems in the network.

Comment: @Ani Sunny: Yes, that's what I meant too. You have already done it, but **instead of sending code, send just the function name and arguments**. Really, it's that easy. Try it! And start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of one approach to networking and graphics, take a look at https://launchpad.net/game